# Passing JS variable to MongoDb query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, pymongo

I currently have a query that I want to execute where a variable containing a string is passed into it.

`{"$and":[{"name":{"$regex": "^cpa", "$options":"i"}}, {"organism": selectedOrganism}]}`

This is passed into the `find()` method; however, in the console, it returns an error message `Uncaught (in promise) Error: $regex requires regular expression` and won't execute the query. Any suggestions on how to fix this?
I've also tried creating a `new RegExp('^cpa','i')` but had the same error

edit- even hard coding in the value /^cpa/ into the query without being a string produces the same error

Comment: how did you use `RegExp`?

Comment: Can you post the full query and an example document. At face value your `$and` looks fine.

Comment: Are you referring to the Mongo Shell when you write `console`? Sure, this query will fail in the mongo shell but not using `pymongo` atop the python mongodb driver.